# gitlab pre-receive hook custom bash script

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, githooks

I need help about how to write a bash script for gitlab server-side pre-receive hook with the below customization(i.e.. user has to enter the below details before push),if that commit doesn't follow below things that commit must be declined.

```
  Fault Id: <GIT issue id>
  Epic JIRA id : <somename>
  Comments: <free text>
```

my sample script is:

```
#! /bin/bash 
echo "Checking whether git commit has following release pattern or not !!" 
ref_name=$1 
ref=$3 
msg=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1 $ref | sed '$d') 
result=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1 $ref | sed '$d' | grep releaseTag=v.*) 
echo "New ref received, ref is: $ref to ref name: $ref_name and commit msg is: $$ msg" 
if [[ -z "${result}" ]] 
then 
echo "######## Requested git commit msg didn't follow the pattern, hence rejecting, follow this pattern releaseTag=v1.11 #########" 
exit 1 
fi
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please show us some effort, like code or links to documentation. What have you achieved so far?

Comment: #! /bin/bash
echo "Checking whether git commit has following release pattern or not !!"
ref_name=$1
ref=$3
msg=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1 $ref | sed '$d')
result=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1 $ref | sed '$d' | grep releaseTag=v.*)
echo "New ref received, ref is: $ref to ref name: $ref_name and commit msg is: $$
msg"
if [[ -z "${result}" ]]
then
 echo "######## Requested git commit msg didn't follow the pattern, hence rejectt
ing, follow this pattern releaseTag=v1.11 #########"
 exit 1
fi

Comment: the above script is just to test if the commit message doesn't have "releaseTag=v*" the commit would be rejected by the hook

Comment: Answers do not belong into the comment section

Comment: added to question now

Comment: Please indent code with 4 spaces and use line breaks so the code is readable